# Rename `layout` tag to `keyboard-layout`

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Pretty much all of the [questions tagged "layout"](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout) are about keyboard layouts. I just cleaned up a couple questions that were tagged `layout` but were about the [layout of the desktop environment](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4876/reactivate-the-desktop-function), and the [layout of the window controls](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/22064/windows-controls-layout-not-changed-after-configuring-through-elementary-tweaks). I've also [added a snippet (excerpt)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/24508) to the tag's wiki, to offer guidance to other people wishing to use the tag.

As per the [meta.SX recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag), I'm asking for a moderator to rename the `layout` tag to `keyboard-layout`, which is both more explicit and in line with other tags like [keyboard-shortcuts](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed and merged, synonym put in place.